# Feign Exception UnsupportedMediaType during POST call to Jira rest endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, jira, jira-rest-api, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have been trying to programmatically create version for a Jira project using Spring Cloud Feign.

I am following https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-project-versions/#api-rest-api-2-version-post

I am able to successfully execute the POST call via Postman, with request payload like :

```
  {
        "name": "ABC 2022.01.000",
        "archived": false,
        "released": true,
        "projectId": 30500
    }
```

However, when I try to create it through the feign client I get below exception :

```
Caused by: feign.FeignException$UnsupportedMediaType: [415] during [POST] to [https://jira.abc.com/rest/api/2/version] [JiraFeignClient#createVersion(VersionDTO)]: []
```

My feign client method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/rest/api/2/version")
ResponseEntity<Object> createVersion(@RequestBody VersionDTO versionDTO);
```

**VersionDTO.java :**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class VersionDTO {

    private String name;

    private Boolean archived;

    private Boolean released;
    
    private Long projectId;
}
```

Not sure what's wrong with my DTO.
Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add an 'accept' header with the expected content type.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't that something which the framework takes care of behind the scene as I am already declaring it to accept the a DTO which will eventually be serialized to json string. However, I had also tried the `consumes = "application/json"`. But that too never worked.

Comment: Check the 'content-type' header as well.

Comment: I did that by adding the `produces = "application/json"`. The 415 error is now gone. Really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add,

**@PostMapping(value = "/calculate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)**

Both **server controller** and **client's feign interface**.